# Conditional attributes and methods in rails serializer 0.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

```
class Api::V1::BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :status, :name, :author_name, :published_date

  attributes :conditional_attributes if condition_1?
  belongs_to :user if condition_2?
end
```

Here I want to put condition on action basic of the controller.

For example I will like to send conditional_attributes for only index action and not for other actions.

But rails "active_model_serializers", "~> 0.10.0" does not give any such things according to my knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```rb
class Api::V1::BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :status, :name, :author_name, :published_date

  attribute :conditional_attribute, if: :some_condition?
  belongs_to :conditional_association, if: :some_other_condition?

  private

  def some_condition?
    # some condition
  end

  def some_other_condition?
    # some other condition
  end
end
```

You can also use `:unless` for negated conditions.

You can use `instance_options` or `instance_reflections` in your conditions if you need them (see https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/howto/passing_arbitrary_options.md) or you can use `scope`s (see https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#scope)

Note: To the best of my knowledge, this only works with `attribute` and association methods – it doesn't work with `attributes` (see https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/lib/active_model/serializer.rb#L204-L210) since it doesn't pass options along.

I read your comment regarding sticking with AM Serializers, but I'll still point it out: If you're looking for a more robust and flexible solution than AM Serializers, [jsonapi-serializer](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer#conditional-attributes) or [Blueprinter](https://github.com/procore/blueprinter/) work quite well and both have support for conditional fields as well as conditional associations.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to render from the controller.

You can pass options to your serializer from the call to render:

```rb
  render json: @track, serializer: Api::V1::BookSerializer, return_user: return_user?, return_extra_attributes: return_extra_attributes?
```

You can then access that option in your serializer definition,  via `@instance_options[:your_option]`.

Here, you would likely have something like:

```rb
class Api::V1::BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :status, :name, :author_name, :published_date

  attributes :conditional_attributes if return_conditional_attributes?
  belongs_to :user if return_user?

  def return_conditional_attributes?
    @instance_options[:return_extra_attributes]
  end

  def return_user?
    @instance_options[:return_user]
  end
end
```

`return_extra_attributes?` and `return_extra_attributes?` would be method defined in your controller

documentation here: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/howto/passing_arbitrary_options.md

Comment: This code is simply wrong: You can't access instance variables on a class level.

Comment: You're right, I went too fast and will make the edit. I did run similar code though, which works